# Forbidden error with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason we are getting a "Server response was not a "200 OK" Can anyone help explain the error and a possible solution?

LINK: https://portal.casa.gov.au/erec/

```
Server response was not a '200 OK'.
Client Request Details
POST /erectest/servlet/repos/run/aw001_repository.op004_about

params=<?xml version="1.0" ?><PARAMS_IN> <PARAM><ARGNAME>component</ARGNAME><ARGVALUE><![CDATA[undefined]]></ARGVALUE></PARAM> <PARAM><ARGNAME>operation</ARGNAME><ARGVALUE><![CDATA[undefined]]></ARGVALUE></PARAM> <PARAM><ARGNAME>dtd</ARGNAME><ARGVALUE><![CDATA[undefined]]></ARGVALUE></PARAM> </PARAMS_IN>
Server Response Details
403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 778

<HTML><HEAD> <TITLE>Invalid Webpage</TITLE> </HEAD> <BODY> <FONT face="Helvetica"> <big><strong></strong></big><BR> </FONT> <blockquote> <TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%"> <TR><TD> <FONT face="Helvetica"> <big>Invalid Webpage (policy_denied)</big> <BR> <BR> </FONT> </TD></TR> <TR><TD> <FONT face="Helvetica"> <p><b>That page does not exist</b></p><p>I'm sorry, you tried to reach a page that is not on the site.</p> </FONT> </TD></TR> <TR><TD> <FONT face="Helvetica"> Please return to the CASA website and navigate from there. </FONT> </TD></TR> <TR><TD> <FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2> <BR> For assistance, please contact the CASA IT Support at ICTSupport@casa.gov.au </FONT> </TD></TR> </TABLE> </blockquote> </FONT> </BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Sounds like a 403. The server is not allowing you to connect.

Comment: This is what the page returns: 

`That page does not exist

I'm sorry, you tried to reach a page that is not on the site.
Please return to the CASA website and navigate from there.

For assistance, please contact the CASA IT Support at ICTSupport@casa.gov.au` Are you sure `/erectest/servlet/repos/run/aw001_repository.op004_about` exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 403 Forbidden error, which means you are not authorised/authenticated to view that page.